# How to add reference package into Eclipse Pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Currently, I have a 'Python package' name oasPython. This package contains Python api to work with OpenAccess and installed from /tool/oasPython3

1. Create a python file as below

   ```
   import oa
   import time

   timer = oa.oaTimer()

   time.sleep(1)

   print "That took %0.2f seconds" % timer.getElapsed()
   ```
2. Add */tool/oasPython3* to *PYTHONPATH*
3. Run the csh file and it print the result

But when I create a Pydev project from Eclipse, the editor can not see the method oa.oaTimer() and show the error

[image]

How can I add all reference of this package to develop using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a third party module, you should install it in the interpreter (inside site-packages) and PyDev should find it (this is what a `pip install oa` would do if there was an `oa`).

If you already did that, try adding `oa` to the `forced builtins` (look for `forced builtins` in http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html for details).

Now, it seems that PyDev is even having trouble with the `time` package in your example, so, you probably have some issue in your interpreter configuration (usually this is the result of a firewall which blocks communication to the shell that is spawned to collect runtime information from Python -- see: http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-WhenIdoacodecompletion%2CPyDevhangs%2CwhatcanIdo%3F for more info -- the error log may also contain entries related to that -- see: http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F for how to get it).

Comment: oa is Python wrapper of a package developed by C++. I added oa into the forced builtins of Python interpreter. But after scanning the namespace, it does not see the subclass so it still show the marker error